# Target range coordinates outside sheet dimensions

Tags: google-apps-script

The following code used to work just fine to move rows from one sheet to another based on a criteria in column 7 of the source row.

Now I get the error message that "The coordinates of the target range are outside the dimensions of the sheet."

Would greatly appreciate any help!

Thanks!

```js
function moveDispos() {
  Logger.clear();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("XXXXXXX");
  var startRow = 2;
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var ColToWatch = 7;
  var moves = [];
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();


  for (var i = startRow - 1; i <= lastRow - 1; i++) {

    var rowVal = data[i][6];
    if (rowVal === "XXXXX") {
      moves.push(Number(i + 1));
    }
  }

  var moveFrom = "XXXXXXX";
  var moveTo = "XXXX XXXXXX";
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName(moveFrom);
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(moveTo);

  for (var i = 0; i < moves.length; i++) {

    move(moves[i] - i, sourceSheet, targetSheet);
  }
}

function move(sourceRow, sourceSheet, targetSheet) {

  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(sourceRow, 1, 1, sourceSheet.getLastColumn());
  var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getDataRange().getLastRow() + 1, 1);

  sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange);
  sourceSheet.deleteRow(sourceRow);
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that you have too many rows or columns.

Comment: Are you sure its move(moves[i] - i?  Could that equal 0 or negative?

Comment: @jon_win Cooper has the right idea. Use Logger to get the value of `getLastRow()`; you could also try `Logger.log("the target range = "+targetRange.GetA1Notation());`. There's a great deal you can do to troubleshoot this. When you've got some data, please come back and tell us what you found.